# PHP mailer is not working for CWP ( control web panel CentOs ) email setup

Tags: php, email, centos, phpmailer, centos-web-panel

I created new email Id for domain https://www.srirangapankajam.in/

Below are the email ID details.

Email Login URL : https://server.we3.in:2031/roundcube/

Email Id : info@srirangapankajam.in

Password : *******

I try to login login using above credentials but showing server error & also can't sent email using PHP library.

I also raised big in github https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/1715

I used following code to send a mail.

```
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                       // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'server.we3.in';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'info@srirangapankajam.in';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '*****';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                                  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port       = 587;                               // TCP port to connect to
    $mail->setFrom('info@srirangapankajam.in', 'Testing');
    $mail->addAddress('siddharthundare@gmail.com'); 
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
```

Below error I get when try to sent mail using SMTP:

2019-04-29 09:29:21 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 server.we3.in ESMTP Postfix
2019-04-29 09:29:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost

2019-04-29 09:29:21 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-server.we3.in250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 204800000250-ETRN250-STARTTLS250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-8BITMIME250 DSN

2019-04-29 09:29:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2019-04-29 09:29:21 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

2019-04-29 09:29:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2019-04-29 09:29:21
2019-04-29 09:29:21
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Comment: Please read the troubleshooting guide. Your connection is failing immediately after STARTTLS, which usually indicates that your CA certificates are out of date. The guide goes into great detail about this.

Comment: Thanks @Synchro I added below code and working fine.



$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);

Comment: Really, don't do that. As the docs say, it's just hiding the problem and making your app vulnerable. Fix it properly.